# URL expiry parameter for retrieving option chains from Google

Tags: url, stockquotes, google-finance

http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&output=json

This URL returns the immediate expiry AAPL option chains from Google.

What is the tag to add to the URL to get an option chain with a different expiry?

In YQL, you can use "m=2015-01", for example.  But I could not find the tag for Google.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=AAPL&expd=11&expm=7&expy=2014&output=json

You can get the d,m,y value from the front month json document you downloaded without specifying the expiration date.